# Angular - Test simple Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I tried so hard, but it seems like I can't figure out how to correctly create the spec.ts file (in order to have a 100% code coverage) for a simple interceptor like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService, private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    // Handle cookies
    request = request.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'X-Csrf-Token': this.cookieService.get(Constants.COOKIES_KEYS.DTM_CSRF_TOKEN),
        SessionId: this.cookieService.get(Constants.COOKIES_KEYS.DTM_SESSION_ID)
      })
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

This is the point that I have reached so far:

```
describe('AuthInterceptor', () => {
  let interceptor: AuthInterceptor;
  let cookieService: CookieService;

  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AuthInterceptor]
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    interceptor = TestBed.inject(AuthInterceptor);
    cookieService = TestBed.inject(CookieService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(
    'should replace request headers',
    waitForAsync(() => {
      const endpoint = `${environment.apiHost}/${environment.apiUrl}/v1/user`;
      const mockReq = new HttpRequest('GET', endpoint);
      const next: HttpHandler = {
        handle: () => {
          return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>(subscriber => {
            subscriber.complete();
          });
        }
      };
      const cookieServiceGetSpy = spyOn(cookieService, 'get');
      cookieServiceGetSpy.withArgs(Constants.COOKIES_KEYS.DTM_CSRF_TOKEN).and.returnValue('testToken');
      cookieServiceGetSpy.withArgs(Constants.COOKIES_KEYS.DTM_SESSION_ID).and.returnValue('testSessionId');
      interceptor.intercept(mockReq, next).subscribe(response => {
        expect(response).toBeTruthy();
        expect(mockReq.headers.get('X-Csrf-Token')).toBe('testToken');
        expect(mockReq.headers.get('SessionId')).toBe('testSessionId');
      });
    })
  );
});
```

My main problem is that "expect" calls are not triggered after the "intercept" subscription is performed (first scenario wihtouth the "waitForAsync" clause), nor are recognized by Karma when inserted inside a "waitForAsync" clause.

Would you mind showing the most correct way to test a very basic interceptor like this?

Thank you in advance.

A.M.

Comment: `can't figure out how to correctly create the spec.ts file` I believe the Angular CLI creates this file for you when you create an interceptor. It looks quite like any other spec file.

Comment: Hello @MikeS., obviously I mean how to create and fill it in to have a 100% coverage. I know that the CLI generates it automatically, but you need to fill it in by yourself... :-)

Comment: I see, maybe `create` isn't the right word to use then ;) Can you paste the `.spec.ts` file for this intereceptor to see what you have tried so far? (At the very least, this would be the bare setup created by the CLI)

Comment: I have updated my original post with the spec.ts file I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this issue by adjusting the spec.ts file as follows:

```
describe('AuthInterceptor', () => {
  let interceptor: AuthInterceptor;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AuthInterceptor]
    });
    interceptor = TestBed.inject(AuthInterceptor);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should replace request headers', done => {
    const mockReq = new HttpRequest('GET', '/test');
    const requestCloneSpy = spyOn(mockReq, 'clone');
    const next: any = {
      handle: () => {
        return of({ status: ApiResponseStatus.OK } as ApiResponse);
      }
    };
    interceptor.intercept(mockReq, next).subscribe(() => {
      expect(requestCloneSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```